# JTextField select all content when focus gained

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, focuslistener

I have a class implements FocusListener, inside the class got a lot of JTextField, I want all of them select all when the focus gained. This is my `focusGained()` function:

```
@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
{
    JTextField txt = (JTextField)fe.getComponent();
    txt.selectAll();
}
```

I try to convert `fe` to component then `selectAll()`, but it doesn't works. Any idea about this?

Comment: txt.selectAll(); should be wrapped into invokeLater - moved to the end of EDT, reason is because the Focus is asynchronous, with significant delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `getSource()`

```
((JTextField)fe.getSource()).selectAll();
```

---

I'd personnally check the `instanceof` `fe.getSource()`

```
@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
    if (!(fe.getSource() instanceof JTextField)) return;
    JTextField txt = (JTextField)fe.getSource();
    txt.selectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, so I assume the listener is not registered at the JTextField. You have to do sth. like this (notify the addFocusListener method):

```
public class MyClass implements FocusListener {
  public JTextField createTextField() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField();

    //add this class as a listener to the textfield
    field.addFocusListener(this);

    return field;
  }

  @Override
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
    JTextField txt = (JTextField)fe.getComponent();
    txt.selectAll();
  }

  @Override
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
  }
}
```